# Zurb Foundation 4 : grid first & last column padding

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Foundation grid system, and my aim is to removes the left padding of the first column and the right padding of the last column (so row content's bounds are verticaly align with above content's bound).

Like in Bootstrap where first and last columns don't have paddings on them and I'd like to do something like that.

My understanding is that adding `collapse` to the row will remove gutters between all columns.

Thanks